# Android app that compares the permissions of 2 apps

Tags: android, privacy

I'm looking for an **Android app** (or a website) that compares the **permissions** of 2 given apps.

The apps to be analysed are **not** installed on the Android device, and they could be provided by specifying their names or Google Play links, or somehow shared from the Google Play app itself; the result should be some sort of a table with a **side-by-side comparison** of the permissions required to install/use those apps.

The app (or the service provided by a website) should be preferably free to
use, even though I could also accept/evaluate paid options.

I could probably write such app by myself, it shouldn't be too difficult (see
[How to get Android app's permissions programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385957/how-to-get-apps-permission-for-each-app-how-to-do-it-programmatically-on-andro) on StackOverflow), but I was wondering if there's anything already available.

Comment: Could you find anything good? I was looking for the exact thing